# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException Error thrown when I tried my custom driver class to register with Spring JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I tried to register my driver class so that my spring application uses custom driver internally ? My application.properties file config is as follows

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5438/postgres
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=postgres
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.example.ksql.KDriver


## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

#Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

server.port=8080
```

Basically, I have implemented java.sql interfaces and inside override methods I am making actual db method calls like postgres, mysql etc.

But when I run my application it shows error like -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class com.example.ksql.KDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:541) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) [spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) [spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1312) [spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1301) [spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at com.example.demo.SamplesJavaApplication.main(SamplesJavaApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class com.example.ksql.KDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1389) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1309) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class com.example.ksql.KDriver
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to instantiate class com.example.ksql.KDriver
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:499) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperty.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:460) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder$MappedDataSourceProperties.set(DataSourceBuilder.java:355) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder.build(DataSourceBuilder.java:181) ~[spring-boot-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration.createDataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:48) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.dataSource(DataSourceConfiguration.java:90) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.7.jar:2.6.7]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.19.jar:5.3.19]
    ... 36 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.ksql.KDriver.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1825) ~[na:1.8.0_342]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.setDriverClassName(HikariConfig.java:495) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    ... 46 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I want to know is it really a right way to use custom driver class internally by jpa or I have to do something else ??

My driver class looks like this -

```
package com.example.ksql;

//import com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver;
import org.postgresql.Driver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Logger;



public class KDriver implements java.sql.Driver {
    public Driver wrappedDriver;

    private String _url;
    private String _username;
    private String _password;

    private String _databaseName;

    private Integer _version = 1;
    private Connection _connection;
    public Boolean _isConnected = false;

    private String _lastInsertId = "-1";

    public KDriver(String url, String user, String password) throws SQLException {

        _url = url;
        _username = user;
        _password = password;

    }

    @Override
    public Connection connect(String _url, Properties info) throws SQLException {

        wrappedDriver = new Driver();
        _connection = wrappedDriver.connect(_url, info);
        Connection kobj = new KConnection(_connection);
        return kobj;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean acceptsURL(String url) throws SQLException {
        boolean acceptsURL = wrappedDriver.acceptsURL(url);
        return acceptsURL;
    }

    @Override
    public DriverPropertyInfo[] getPropertyInfo(String url, Properties info) throws SQLException {
        return new DriverPropertyInfo[0];
    }

    @Override
    public int getMajorVersion() {
       int getMajor = wrappedDriver.getMajorVersion();
        return getMajor;
    }


    @Override
    public int getMinorVersion() {
        int getMinor = wrappedDriver.getMinorVersion();
        return getMinor;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean jdbcCompliant() {
        boolean jdbcCompliant = wrappedDriver.jdbcCompliant();
        return jdbcCompliant;
    }

    @Override
    public Logger getParentLogger() throws SQLFeatureNotSupportedException {
        return wrappedDriver.getParentLogger();
    }
}
```

Comment: A sql Driver needs to have a no-args constructor. Which, if you check the **full stacktrace** will also be something that that is telling you. Please include the **full stacktrace**!

Answer (score 0):

You seem what you want to use postgress so configure a standard postgress drivers and add postgress driver jar with maven.

```
spring.database.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

Not strange

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.example.ksql.KDriver
```